# How to convert this asp.net usercontrol to work in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, user-controls

I have a need to port one of my asp.net user controls over for use in MVC 3 but it looks like MVC isn't setup to support user controls.

I see posts claiming user controls are an anti-pattern of MVC. I'm not interested in a debate on that I just need to get this user control ported over regardless of what side of that supposed fence your on. I don't see this being a html helper either. Placing mountains of javascript inside double quotes as a parameter to a helper negates any benefit due to loss of readability, intelli-sense support, maintainability.

The control is called the *ScriptCompressor*. Its purpose is to take the place of all inline script tags on the page. During rendering all of the inline javascript that ultimately make up a call to a dynamic page are combined and placed into either one or two script "wrappers" at the bottom/top of the page. The whole point of this control is to reduce page size and improve load performance by minification and compression of all inline scripts. There is no view state involved it simply outputs a script tag and javascript.

How do I call my existing control inside an MVC 3 Razor page?

Example from ASP.net usage:

```
<uc:ScriptCompressor Compress="true">
    var myGlobalVar = "something";

</uc:ScriptCompressor>

<uc:ScriptCompressor Compress="true" UseReadyWrapper="true">
    var _registrationViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    ...
</uc:ScriptCompressor>

<uc:ScriptCompressor Compress="true" UseReadyWrapper="true">
    var _addNewUserViewModel = new AddNewUserViewModel();
    ...
</uc:ScriptCompressor>
```

Uncompressed Output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myGlobalVar = "something";
$(function () {
    var _registrationViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    var _addNewUserViewModel = new AddNewUserViewModel();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conjunction of 2 custom HTML helpers to replace your existing server side control:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private const string GlobalsQueueKey = "_globals_queue_";
    private const string ReadyWrapperQueueKey = "_ready_wrapper_queue_";

    [Obsolete("Don't use inline scripts, that's what javascript files are meant for. And yeah, there are pretty nifty javascript compressors out there. Not to mention that in ASP.NET MVC 4 there's the bundling and minification functionality built-in. So use this helper just for fun not in a real application that you intend to put in production.")]
    public static IHtmlString RegisterInlineScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool compress, bool useReadyWrapper, Func<object, HelperResult> action)
    {
        var queueKey = useReadyWrapper ? ReadyWrapperQueueKey : GlobalsQueueKey;
        var queue = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[queueKey] as Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>;
        if (queue == null)
        {
            queue = new Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>();
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[queueKey] = queue;
        }
        queue.Enqueue(action);

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;                
    }

    [Obsolete("Don't use inline scripts, that's what javascript files are meant for. And yeah, there are pretty nifty javascript compressors out there. Not to mention that in ASP.NET MVC 4 there's the bundling and minification functionality built-in. So use this helper just for fun not in a real application that you intend to put in production.")]
    public static IHtmlString InlineScripts(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var globalsQueue = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[GlobalsQueueKey] as Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>> ?? new Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>();
        var readyWrapperQueue = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[ReadyWrapperQueueKey] as Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>> ?? new Queue<Func<object, HelperResult>>();
        if (!globalsQueue.Any() && !readyWrapperQueue.Any())
        {
            // Nothing to compress, nothing to output
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var writer = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer;


        writer.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");

        using (var globalsWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            foreach (var item in globalsQueue)
            {
                item(null).WriteTo(globalsWriter);
            }
            var globals = globalsWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            writer.Write(Compress(globals));
        }

        using (var readyWrapperWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            foreach (var item in readyWrapperQueue)
            {
                item(null).WriteTo(readyWrapperWriter);
            }

            var readyWrapper = readyWrapperWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

            writer.Write(
                string.Format("$(function() {{{0}}});", Compress(readyWrapper))
            );
        }

        writer.Write("</script>");

        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
    }

    private static string Compress(string script)
    {
        // TODO: wheel reinvention code from your existing
        // server side control to be put here to compress
        return script;
    }
}
```

and then you could have a view in which you register multiple inline scripts:

```
@Html.RegisterInlineScript(true, false, 
    @<text>
        var myGlobalVar = "something";
    </text>
)

@Html.RegisterInlineScript(true, true, 
    @<text>
        var _registrationViewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    </text>
)

@Html.RegisterInlineScript(true, true, 
    @<text>
        var _addNewUserViewModel = new AddNewUserViewModel();
    </text>
)
```

and somewhere in your `_Layout` output them:

```
@Html.InlineScripts()
```

OK, now for your real application checkout the bundling and minification support in ASP.NET MVC 4: http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-bundling-and.html